# Elasticsearch Deployment on AWS : Beanstalk app server vs standalone ec2

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on a java application, hosted on amazon elastic beanstalk running tomcat 7. The app uses elasticsearch for indexing and searching entities.

Can I install the elastic search service on the beanstalk server itself ? Is it a good strategy for scaling the application in the future, where each beanstalk instance would have elasticsearch running on it? The other option is to create a standalone ec2 instance with just elasticsearch running on it, but it seems like an overkill.

**Edit**

Elasticsearch works fine on a single beanstalk server. Not sure if having an elasticsearch worker per beanstalk instance is good for scaling though.

Comment: Having one elasticsearch worker is not a bad idea but like I said you could eventually need 2 workers per 1 application node because not everything scales at the same rate. Starting off it will probably work just fine, just monitor the situation and if you need to make the required changes to your architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you don't want to put multiple services on the same instances. Not everything scales at the same rate or has the same hardware requirements. Every application goes through multiple changes as its traffic scales up you won't have every answer right now and you don't have to do everything by the book. If you have a small cluster I think you're right and you shouldn't worry about creating a separate EC2 instance. If your application is successful you may decide sooner than later to move the cluster.

Please note that I haven't used beanstalk, but it appears that it is possible to do. However, it may be easier to do it in EC2 or OpsWorks.

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx3MEVKS0A4G7R5/Deploying-Elasticsearch-with-OpsWorks

More information about customizing your beanstalk environment. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

Comment: Thanks for the input! As you'd mentioned, for now an elasticsearch worker per beanstalk seems like a good choice, and is working quite well so far on AWS